# Material for MkDocs - activating Glightbox stops search field appearing

Tags: mkdocs

If I add the following to my mkdocs.yml:

```
plugins:
 - glightbox
```

Then lightbox works - I can click on images to zoom into them - however, the Search field disappears. If I remove those lines, the Search field is back. How can I have glightbox and Search at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same issue. just add search to the plugins.

```
plugins:
  - search
  - glightbox
```

https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/plugins/search/